# How to fix the error lines override bar c3 js

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I am working on a project and use c3 js library (don't use d3 js) And now I'm having a problem, that is when using c3 js and using lines, lines override bar chart, I cannot use `z-index` to make bar graphs override on lines?

Error:

[image]

Comment: Hi, can also show your code, please? (But not as an image, please add the code as text to your question via the edit button :) ). Thanks!

Comment: I'm very sorry, I don't know the web rules, i fixed

Comment: https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1938 --- use the trick here to move the bar chart to be drawn last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st try setting the gridlines

```
grid: {
  lines: {
    front: false
  }
}
```

The above really should work per https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/462

If this doesn't work did you pick up the c3.css file - see https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1962

```
# style_grid.css
.c3-xgrid-line line {
    stroke: blue;
    z-index: 400;
}
```